# Boostrap 3: Validate wysihtml5 editor for text area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, wysiwyg

Am using the bootstrap validator for validating the form. In that i added the wysiwyg editor for the textarea field (https://github.com/Waxolunist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower).

I need to validate the textarea as required field. I can get the value of textarea using **$('.textarea').val();**

CODE:

Is there any other validation we can perform on wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
ignore: ":hidden:not(textarea)",
```

and it's working, just add `required` class to textarea.